# Make certain JComboBox values not selectable

Tags: jcombobox

How can I make a combobox value not selectable by user?

```
String [] names = {"john", "jack", "frank"};
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(names);
lezioniBox.insertItemAt("-- Choose a name --", 0); 
lezioniBox.setSelectedIndex(0); \\ I wanted to have a sort of hint
```

But I don't want to have `-- Choose a name --` selectable. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, however, you can add some validation code for when the user attempts to do something with your JComboBox.  If they choose that option, then you can throw an error.  This can be done with an event listener on the JComboBox, or if this is being submitted in a form-like format it can validate when the user selects OK, Save, or whenever you have your submit button set to.